# enable_if with enum in g++ 4.8.1

Tags: c++, templates, enums, g++, clang

I want to use SFINAE based on an enum with g++.

I get an error when compiling with g++ (4.8.1):
 `error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’`

clang(3.2) compiles it without that error.

(a2 and b2 will lead in both cases to a compiler error which is intended!)

**Edit:**
As sharth [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22737281/1935553) the code is is buggy and clang 3.2 was just "nice".

Is there a different way to achieve this functionality?

```
#include <type_traits>

enum Foo {
  A = 3,
  B = 4
};

template<Foo T> class Bar {
  const Foo foo_;

public:

  Bar() : foo_(T) {}

  template<typename = typename std::enable_if<T == A>::type>
  Bar(int x, int y, int z) : foo_(T) {}


  template<typename = typename std::enable_if<T == B>::type>
  Bar(int x, int y, int z, int w) : foo_(T) {}

  ~Bar() {}

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  Bar<A> a1(1,2,3);
  Bar<A> a2(1,2,3,4);
  Bar<B> b1(1,2,3,4);
  Bar<B> b2(1,2,3);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you have the template declaration written will not allow a substitution failure. You can use a default dummy template parameter like this to fix it:

```c++
template<Foo U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<U == A>::type>
Bar(int x, int y, int z) : foo_(T) {}

template<Foo U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<U == B>::type>
Bar(int x, int y, int z, int w) : foo_(T) {}
```

And you will get the expected behavior. [**Here is a demo.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f931ba14568533)